# Calculate longitude on the 0 degree latitude line, knowing the starting point (latitude,longitude) and azimuth on ellipsoid Earth model

Tags: matlab, geolocation, geometry, latitude-longitude, azimuth

Input: 
Observer (Lat,Lon WGS84 coordinates) and an azimuth angle (degrees)

Output: 
By considering only the 0 degrees latitude line, I am trying to get the intersection longitude point from the observer point with the given azimuth. I am considering the ellipsoid Earth model.

Comment: you should probably re-iterate or clarify your question in the body of your post. You're likely to receive down votes for not doing so... just a tip!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I reformulated it. is that better?

Comment: Do you have Mapping Toolbox available, or are you using vanilla Matlab?

Comment: I do have the mapping toolbox. But `track1` provides an answer if the lat/lon, azimuth and length is known.  In this case, we don't know the length. We just want to intersect the line with the 0 degree latitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Mapping Toolbox available, you can use the `track1` function.  See the Mathworks documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/track1.html?refresh=true.

Answer (score 0):

Basic formula is

```
lon(lat, lon, Z) = lon - atan(sin(lat)*tan(Z))
```

(Beware that your calculator uses degrees)